# Load PDF file in newWin

Tags: jquery

I have a small program to load various PDF files about 100 or so I am not sure this is the best way to manage this task but it works with one exception Permission denied ERROR when I run this code in debug mode the program has erratic behavior when I try to use this line of code newWin.moveTo(0,0); and this is were the ERROR occurs
You will need your own PDF files

I would appreciate help with the error and if anyone has a better design concept please feel free to speak up

thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>PDF Select</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><!-- this is the path within the folder-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//$("<span>Download a PDF of </span>").insertBefore("a[href$=.pdf]");
$("#findWhat").change(function(){
pageone();
});

});

function pageone(){

var winProp = "width = 1015, height = 760";
var X = $("#findWhat").val();//What number selected
//alert("my value " + X);
if (X == 1){
var newWin = open(href = "first.pdf","aWin",winProp);
newWin.moveTo(0,0);
$("#findWhat").val(0);
}
if (X == 2){
var newWin = open(href = "second.pdf","aWin",winProp);
newWin.moveTo(0,0);
$("#findWhat").val(0);
}
if (X == 3){
var newWin = open(href = "third.pdf","aWin",winProp);
newWin.moveTo(0,0);
$("#findWhat").val(0);
}
}

</script>
</head>

<body alink="blue" link="black" vlink="red">


<p><a href = "first.pdf" target = "_blank">TPN Order Form</a></p>
<p><a href = "second.pdf" target = "_blank">Integrilin Dosing Protocol</a></p>
<p><a href = "third.pdf" target = "_blank">Enoxaparin Dosing</a></p>

<p>
<select id = "findWhat">
<option value = "0"></option>
<option value = "1">TPN</option>
<option value = "2">Integrilin Dosing Protocol</option>
<option value = "3">Enoxaparin Dosing</option>
</select>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.open('url/to/your.pdf', 'windowName', "height=600,width=800");`

Comment: Yes that will open the window but I need to position the newWin at the top of the screen this is the line of code giving me fits newWin.moveTo(0,0);@SpYk3HH